# What are my chances of passing tomorrow's exam? Plus advice

Tags: probability

I have an exam tomorrow, for which I must study 56 questions. The teacher will ask 4 questions at random (he has a big lottery roller), so obviously once a question has been asked, it can't be asked again. Now, out of those 56 questions I've memorized 42. If I'm not wrong, that means I have a 75% chance of knowing the first question that my teacher takes out. But what are the chances that I know the next 3 questions?

Also, would you say I have a good chance of passing my exam? If you were in my situation, would you review the questions you already know to make sure you don't mess up, or would you try to memorize a couple more?
I hope I'm posting this in the right place, if not let me know. Thank you!

Comment: How many questions do you need to answer correctly to pass your exam?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this comment earlier! Three is good enough to pass, sometimes two if you get two very long ones and you know them. But three in almost every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must know all 4 questions to pass your chances are:

$\frac{42}{56}\frac{41}{55}\frac{40}{54}\frac{39}{53} \approx 0.305$

The order of questions is unimportant and every time your teacher asks you a question, this question is removed from the pool of questions. This is the same as drawing balls from an urn without replacement (42 red balls and 14 blue balls, 56 balls in total) and doing it four times. What are the odds of drawing 4 red balls in a row?

**So my advice would be to memorize a couple more.**

Of course, this looks different if you only need to know 3 questions or your teacher asks you 5 questions and you need to know 4 of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I'll take your advice, although I believe knowing 3 questions would be good enough to pass. It also depends on which ones you get, if the first two are very long and you know them he will see you studied and won't ask anymore. But I'll still try to memorize a couple more. I don't think I'll make it to 56 but 48~50 is probably something I could manage. The teacher will only ask 4 questions max.